# What is the best way to show an inherited object in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Lets say I have this:

```
public class Result 
{
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to add another level, like this:

```
public class AssertionFailedResult : Result
{
  public string Expected { get; set; }
  public string Actual { get; set; }
}
```

In WPF, how would I show the simple result one way and the assertion failed result another way?  I'd like to basically make a template based on type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a DataTemplate in a resource dictionary and set the DataType property, but don't set the x:Key property, the framework will associate the DataTemplate to objects based on the object's runtime type. For better or worse, inheritance has no effect. In other words, even if you *didn't* have a template where the DataType was "AssertionFailedResult", the framework would *not* bind objects of type "AssertionFailedResult" to a template where the DataType was "Result".

**EDIT:** Sorry, I got it backwards. DataTemplates *do* have a "polymorphic" behavior. Styles do not. In any case, the frameworks should bind to the DataTemplate with the more specific DataType.

Answer (score 0):

I took Daniel's answer and made an example out of it.  I thought posting the code might be helpful:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWpfApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:SampleWpfApplication="clr-namespace:SampleWpfApplication">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SampleWpfApplication:Result}">
            <Label>Simple Result</Label>            
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SampleWpfApplication:AssertionFailedResult}">
            <Label>Assertion Failed!</Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{Binding Path=Result}" />
</Window>
```

Next, a model class that is the data context of the window:

```
public class Model
{
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

And in the MainWindow, I set the DataContext as follows:

```
DataContext = new Model()
                  {
                      Result = new AssertionFailedResult()
                                   {
                                       Success = false,
                                       Description = "Assertion failed",
                                       Expected = "1",
                                       Actual = "1"
                                   }
                  };
```

So with the DataTemplate, wpf knows how to render the control without any additional direction on my part.  Thanks again, Daniel.